# Column name 'ApplicationUserId' in table 'Tickets' is specified more than once

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, database-design

```
     DB relationship:
              1ApplicationUser : n Tickets
              1ApplicationUser: n Activities
              1Tickets:n Activites
```

I would like to design above database using code first. However,there's error warning

> "Column name 'ApplicationUserId' in table 'Tickets' is specified more
>   than once."

However, I checked there's only one `ApplicationUserId` in Table `Ticket` as shown in below class.

Would anyone please help how to fix it? Thanks.

The entity class are as following:

Ticket Class

```
     public class Ticket
     {
              public int ID { get; set; }
              public Ticket()
              {            TicketCreateDate = DateTime.Now;        }
            public DateTime TicketCreateDate { get; set; } 
            public int TicketCreateBy { get; set; }
            public DateTime TicketCloseDate { get; set; }
            public int TicketCloseBy { get; set; }
            public DateTime LastTicketUpdateDate { get; set; }
            public int LastUpdateBy { get; set; }//Ticket Last Update by 
            public DateTime TicketAssignedDate { get; set; } 
            public int TicketAssignedTo { get; set; } 

            public string TicketType { get; set; }
            public string Priority { get; set; }// Ticket priority
            public string TicketStatus { get; set; }
            public string TicketDescription { get; set; }
            public int DeviceUserID { get; set; }
            public string DeviceBrand { get; set; }
            public string DeviceType { get; set; }

            public virtual ICollection<Activity> Activities { get; set; }
            public int ApplicationUserID { get; set; }
            public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
}
```

Acitivity Class

```
    public class Activity
    {
            public int ID { get; set; }
            public Activity()
            {
                CreatedTime = DateTime.Now;
            }

            public DateTime CreatedTime { get; set; }
            public string ActivityDetails { get; set; } 
            public int ApplicationUserID { get; set; }
            public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
            public int TicketId { get; set; }
            public virtual Ticket Ticket { get; set; }
        }
```

ApplicationUser Class

```
        public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
        {
                public virtual ICollection<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; }
                public virtual ICollection<Activity> Activities { get; set; }
        }
```

Comment: can you tell the relationships between tables ? `1: M` or `M:M` or ?

Comment: Hi Sampath, the DB relationship is as following:
DB relationship:
              1ApplicationUser : n Tickets
              1ApplicationUser: n Activities
              1Tickets:n Activites